# ios 7 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath method - does it need registerClass method

Tags: ios, uitableview, registerclass

I am using ios 7.

Quick question. I have a working program that uses dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath to display cells with two different prototypes. I never used the UITableView registerClass method.

Does this mean that I am not reusing the cells? My thinking is that this is not the case (as I have fixed bugs before in this app which were related to cells retaining prior states).

If I actually use registerClass now (in viewDidLoad for the tableVieW), my data is not being shown - any ideas why?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
I add the registerClass code in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[ProtoCell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"proto1"];
[self.tableView registerClass:[ProtoCell2  class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"proto2"];
```

Comment: "If I actually use registerClass now (in viewDidLoad for the tableVieW), my data is not being shown - any ideas why?" - how can we know? you have not placed any CODE. Registering classs is just a new feature, you can use both methods now. but maybe old method is depricated now

Comment: I added the code to add register class, if that helps.

Comment: @serverman are you using storyboard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the cell is created using prototypes within a storyboard it is not necessary to register the class.

Using

```
 registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier
```

will prevent your view from rendering if it was already declared in Interface Builder. If you registered your cell identifier in storyboard and you are using

```
  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:
```

then you should be reusing cells

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that answers my question!