# Xcode 5.1 UITableView in UIViewController - Custom TableViewCell Outlets are nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a UITableView as a subview in a UIViewController. I'm not using UITableViewController because I have some other content that is not tableview-related taking up part of the screen. I am using storyboards. I have the tableview set up as an outlet, with the viewcontroller being the datasource and delegate. If I use the standard UITableViewCell in this scenario, everything works well and I can load content.

I need to use a custom UITableViewCell for this tableview, so I performed the following steps:

1. Created a UITableView subclass named SWTableViewCell
2. Added a call in viewDidLoad to register the cell with interface builder:     `[self.tableView registerClass:[SWTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`
3. In the storyboard on my tableview, set the prototype cell's Class to SWTableViewCell
4. In the storyboard, set the cell reuse identifier to "Cell"
5. Added some labels to the prototype cell on the storyboard
6. Still in the storyboard, ctrl-dragged from the labels to the SWTableViewCell.h to create outlets
7. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, dequeue and cast the cell to the custom subclass: `SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

The cell variable is the proper type when I check it. It's not a UITableViewCell, but a SWTableViewCell. But none of the outlets are populated. The properties exist, but they are nil. I'm sure there's a connection I must be missing, but i can't think of anything I skipped at this point.

Is this scenario possible, or does it just not work via IB and storyboards?

Comment: who is the file owner of your cell ?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work, I'm testing it with a blank project, I'll let you know

Comment: Looks like removing *registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:* makes it work. I'm looking into why.

Comment: @rdurand wow, just worked for me too. If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it. Wonder what the reason is. That would be interesting to know.

Comment: @MarkStruzinski : I'm looking into it. I've never used *registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:*, so I don't know how it's supposed to work. I'll write an answer and update it as I find info on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the call to

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[SWTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

solves the issue.

I don't know exactly what this method does as I've never used it, so I'll look into it. If anyone has information on wether or not this call is required for something, please tell us !

---

Edit :

So, the idea behind `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is that it tells the tableView how to create new cells. That way, if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does not return a cell (if the queue is empty), the tableView knows how to create a new cell, and you don't need to manually create one).

---

Edit 2 :

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304528/ios-7-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath-method-does-it-need-regis) thread, in which it says :

> If the cell is created using prototypes within a storyboard it is not necessary to register the class.

Simply calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` will "activate" the cell reusing functionality of your tableView.

So `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is to be called only if you manually build your cells, without the use of storyboards.

Comment: @MarkStruzinsky : I updated my answer with more information and a possible fix.

Comment: I removed part of my edit, which was completely wrong about solving the issue (lol)

Comment: I added something, which explains why it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why my cell's IBOutlets were nil. I was calling registerClass:forCellReuseItentifier even though it was in my storyboard. This was causing the prototype cell outlets to not get hooked up.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tips:

Basically there can be 3 ways to create and use `UITableViewCell`s:

1. Use **“prototype” cells** in the storyboard/nib

   (Create cell UI in the storyboard/nib inside `UITableView`)

   You **should not use either** `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` methods. `UIStoryboard` handles it on its own, since you specified the `reuseIdentifier` in the storyboard, the `tableView` knows which cell is associated with which `reuseIdentifier`.
2. Use **a separate nib** for `tableViewCell` UI

   (This might be a way to go when you want to use the same `tableViewCell` in several `tableView`s)

   You **should use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`** method.
3. Do not use nibs, create `tableViewCell` UI **programmatically**

   You **should use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`** method.

Also, note that both `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` should be called before (most often in `viewDidLoad`) `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`method is called. If you registered a class or a nib for the `reuseIdentifier` it is guaranteed that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns a valid cell (unlike `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`).

In your code `Storyboard` registered a `nib` with UI for the cell, but you calling `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` with the same `reuseIdentifier` forced table view to unregister the nib and register the class which was not aware of `IBOutlet`s.