# Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get this error when attempting to populate my table:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = tasks[indexPath.row];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = dictionary[@"key"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [Global getPriority:(NSString *)dictionary[@"key_2"]];

    return cell;
}
```

When I remove the `forIndexPath` the error goes away but then I can use the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

Could somebody please help me?

Also, the table is built programmatically.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: What version of iOS do you use to run this code? The only thing I can guess that you use iOS 5.0, but this method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) is available only from 6.0

Answer (score 1):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` expects that you have previously registered a `nib` or a `class` for the same `reuseIdentifier` (or that you have a `prototype cell` in your `nib`/`storyboard` again with the same `reuseIdentifier`. It also is guaranteed that this method will alwaysreturn a valid cell, so you would never have to creat a `cell` programmatically if your are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method.

If you do want to create your cells programmatically, then you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` paired with your `if (!cell) { cell =... }` code.
For more information check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352587/xcode-5-1-uitableview-in-uiviewcontroller-custom-tableviewcell-outlets-are-nil/22354255#22354255)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue in my code. what i found was I had accidentally attached delegate of UITableView to view of View controller. Change delegate to UIViewController[image]